# Model Evaluate in Keras

Tags: python, keras, evaluate

I am training a model to perform a binary classification through Keras. After my model is trained, I tried evaluate it, like this:

```
# Evaluate the model
print('Evaluate on test data')
loss, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)
print('Test loss: %.4f' % loss)
print('Test accuracy: %.4f' % acc)
```

And I got this result:

```
Evaluate on test data
116/1 - 0s - loss: 0.3099 - accuracy: 0.8793
Test loss: 0.2802
Test accuracy: 0.8793
```

My question is, why the loss values reported are different? i.e, `0.3099` and `0.2802`? Is this some kind of bug? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Isn't `loss = 0.3099` for the last batch of the testing and `Test  loss = 0.2802` the best loss on every batch of the test dataset ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a bug, it makes sense once you are aware how both numbers are computed. Since you set `verbose=2` in your `model.evaluate` call, it shows the progress of batches over the test set.

The accuracy and loss displayed in the progress bar are a exponentially average over batches, as to ease visualization. The loss and accuracy you get as return from `model.evaluate` is the total loss/accuracy averaged over batches, and are the numbers you should consider as final and correct.